# Drag and Drop a file into a shortcut to call a CMD.EXE with the path as a parameter

Tags: file, command-line, drag-and-drop, desktop

I like the Drag/Drop interface very much. Especially to start a simple command-line program from the command shell by dropping a file to a shortcut would be a nice feature (Shortcuts are dropping targets for dragged files).

Unfortunately the shortcut doesn't call the command-line program with the path to the file dropped.

Dropping a file to such a shortcut only starts some kind of a window which disappears immediately. Using a shortcut to call a batch file executes the batch but does not append the dropped file as a path as a parameter.

Any idea how to get a simple solution for this simple dropping target?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of not getting the name of the file to drop is rather trivial: I had coded a CMD.EXE /k in the shortcut to execute the batch file. After removing that and only coding the batch file it works flawlessly.